# How to get image name automatically from destination folder

Tags: php

I am working on a project that resize images. My following code takes an image from upload directory, resizes it and save the output image but the problem is that I have to hard code image name.

I want to get image name automatically from upload directory. Please someone solve my problem.

```
<?php
include('resize_lib.php'); // resize_lib is the library that has functionality of how to resize the image

//focus on this line
$image_path = "upload/something.jpg";// hard coded image name

$resizeObj = new resize($image_path);
$resizeObj -> resizeImage(1536, 1024, 0); // width // height
$resizeObj -> saveImage("new.png", 100);
echo "done...";
?>
```

Comment: Have you tryed `basename()`?

Comment: Use `glob("upload/*.jpg")`

Comment: Are you asking how to get `new.png`? Why can't you just use whatever you pass to `saveImage`?`

Answer (score 0):

Try to get all images files from your uploaded directory `.jpg` or `.png` or `.gif`

```
$files = glob("upload/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

`glob`

> Returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty
>   array if no file matched or FALSE on error.

You can then use `foreach()` loop to set your image name for `$image_path`. By the way you can also select only a single type of image e.g **something.jpg**

```
$files = glob('upload/*.jpg');
```